# FLT from Mochizuki's proof of abc 

Tags: nt.number-theory

If Mochizuki's proof of abc is correct, why would this provide a new proof of FLT?

Edit: In proof of asymptotic FLT, does Mochizuki claim a specific value of n and if so what is this value?

Comment: Enough with Mochizuki + abc, already! If the proof is accepted, then we will all celebrate. Until then, this is fairly pointless.

Comment: I downvoted this because it took about 30 seconds to find the answer, starting from the Wikipedia page on the abc conjecture.

Comment: but unknown yahoos want to know!

Comment: Igor, while I am sure many of us are getting fed up with the rampant speculatory questions regarding Mochizuki and ABC, maybe the people asking are not regular enough on MO (or meta-MO) to be familiar with the ongoing debates about acceptability of such questions. This is not a crime. My impression is that this question is independent of Mochizuki's work and simply asks for why ABC implies FLT. Since this information is easily available on the internet, the question should be closed for not being research level rather than in annoyance at other recent ABC questions. 

Comment: @Vel: I did answer, though (a) this particular @unknown is obviously not a complete MO novice (judging by reputation) and (b) I do agree re the easy availability of the info.

Answer (score 5):

Let us suppose that $x^{n}+y^{n}= z^{n}$ with $x, y,$ and $z$ relatively prime. By the *abc* conjecture, $|x^{n}|\ll |xyz|^{1+\epsilon}$, $|y^{n}|\ll |xyz|^{1+\epsilon}$, and $|z^{n}|\ll |xyz|^{1+\epsilon}$. Therefore, $|xyz|^{n}\ll |xyz|^{3+\epsilon}$ which implies that, for $|xyz|>1$, $n$ is bounded. Unfortunately, this establishes only an *asymptotic* version of FLT. Nevertheless, if we had explicit information regarding the implied constant in the *abc* conjecture, we could in principle determine explicit upper bounds for those $n$'s for which the *abc* conjecture doesn't settle FLT.

**UPDATE (October 26th, 2021)**. In the abstract of "Explicit Estimates in Inter-universal Teichmuller Theory", Mochizuki et. al. we read this:

> In the final paper of a series of papers concerning *inter-universal Teichmüller theory*, Mochizuki verified various *numerically
> non-effective versions of the Vojta, ABC, and Szpiro Conjectures* over
> number fields. In the present paper, we obtain various *numerically effective versions* of Mochizuki’s results... These numerically effective versions imply *effective diophantine results* such as an *effective
> version of the ABC inequality over mono-complex number fields* [i.e.,
> the rational number field or an imaginary quadratic field] and *effective
> versions of conjectures of Szpiro*. We also obtain an explicit estimate
> concerning “Fermat’s Last Theorem” (FLT)—i.e., to the effect that
> FLT holds for prime exponents greater than $1.615\cdot 10^{14}$—which is sufficient to give an alternative proof of the first case of FLT. In the second case of FLT, if one combines the techniques of the present paper with a recent estimate due to [Mihăilescu](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022314X2100055X), then the lower bound $1.615 \cdot 10^{14}$ can be improved to $3.35\cdot 10^{9}$.

If I understand correctly, [this paper was uploaded](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Emotizuki/papers-english.html) to Mochizuki's homepage four months ago. I dared to update my reply because I consider that the lines above give a definite answer to the OP's second question (regardless of what the generalized opinion about IUTT is).

Comment: You need 3 + 3eps not 1 + eps when you bound the product;  from your inequality you could prove there are only finitely many primitive Pythagorean triples. (What is perhaps more interesting is that while abc will yield finiteness of solutions for all n=> 4, it won't for n=3, which is not unexpected since heuristically/analytically one could actually expect an infinitude of solutions for n=3.)

Comment: @quid: That was obviously a typo... Thanks.

Comment: So, with Dimitrov's new preprint at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.03572.pdf , what are the consequences for FLT? Does one get a reasonable estimate for the exponent?

Answer (score 5):

The two answers of J.H.S and Igor Rivin don't really answer the question : they prove FLT
only for an exposant $n$ large enough. 
Since Mochizuki's version of ABC is effective, one could certainly find an effective bound for $n$, and maybe prove by hand the remaining $n$. But as they stand, they are incomplete.

Here is a short proof that Mochizuku implies Fermat. If the proof is correct, since it is also incorrect (cf. the second answer to [this question] by Vasselin Dimitrov), it implies trivially Fermat't last theorem as well as its contrary.

I guess I should explicit my point: it is prematurate to ask precise questions
on the consequence of Mochizuki's proof. As for vague philosophical question, as the one
given in the link above, that have a problem too : they are vague. Let us at least wait for the MO community to accept or not Vasselin Dimitrov's very interesting answer, which
moreover is exactly about the effective version of ABC conjecture needed to answer the PO's question, before asking such questions.

[1] [Philosophy behind Mochizuki's work on the ABC conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106560/philosophy-behind-mochizukis-work-on-the-abc-conjecture)

Answer (score 0):

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/abcConjecture.html